# Trouble with importing Java output into shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, testing

Any help is appreciated:

I am running a simple java currency converter application and trying to test it using conditional bash statements. For this test I am seeking to test when the user doesn't enter any value into the application what the resulting output is. Here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=""

expectedOuput="Please enter correct input"

actualOutput=$(java CurrencyConverter $input)

if [ $expectedOutput == $actualOutput ]; then
echo "Test 1 Passed"
else
echo "Test 1 Failed"
fi
```

I am aiming for the test to fail and echo this, however the script just returns the java error instead of echoing, like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at CurrencyConverter.main(CurrencyConverter.java:12)
```

I am newer to bash scripting so have been changing the syntax, I just cant seem to stop the java error being printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is printed to stderr, so if you want to get it in `actualOutput` (perhaps misleading name now):

```
actualOutput=$(java CurrencyConverter "$input" 2>&1)
```

you can also check the exit status of the `java` command.

Also check misspelled `expectedOuput` and use of quotes.
Use https://www.shellcheck.net/.

And the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` it's definitely something you should fix in your java code.

Comment: Diego, I appreciate you're help greatly, thank you!

After reading your comment, I have changed my script to this:

``
#!/bin/bash

input=""

expectedOutput="Please enter correct input"

actualOutput=$(java CurrencyConverter "$input" 2>&1)

if [ $expectedOutput == $actualOutput ]; then
echo "Test 1 Passed"
else
echo "Test 1 Failed"
fi

``
I am glad that the java error is no longer printing, however there is still an error:

test1.sh: 9: [: Please: unexpected operator

I am confused as "==" should compare strings, unless I am looking in the wrong area?

Thanks,

Ewan

Comment: Sorry, for the poor formatting in my last comment. I tried with one equal operand and this seems to work, perhaps I am confusing syntax! Thanks for your help Diego and have a nice weekend :)

Comment: I guess ` if [[ "$expectedOutput" == "$actualOutput" ]]; then...`